# Android programming crash null pointer exception

Tags: android

hey everyone at the moment im trying to display all the files in a certain folder on the android devices sd card in a `ListView` and so far im having bad luck,It crashes with a nullpointer exception so i was wondering if anyone here could shine some lite on my proble ill post my activity and logcat below and thanks.

Activity

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class ListMobileActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.res);

    }
        public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
            ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
            File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

            f.mkdirs();
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            if (files.length == 0)
                return null;
            else {
                for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
                    MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
            }

            return MyFiles;
        }
        {
        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/RootBox");
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

             }
        });
    }




    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

and logcat

```
05-24 06:42:28.992: E/AndroidRuntime(796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 06:42:28.992: E/AndroidRuntime(796): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.ListMobileActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-24 06:42:28.992: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-24 06:42:28.992: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-24 06:42:28.992: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-24 06:42:28.992: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-24 06:42:28.992: E/AndroidRuntime(796):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: which line is giving the exception?

Comment: at which line does it crashes??

Comment: ill just get the other lines of log

Comment: @user2416330 : change your code as http://pastebin.com/110yPYpA to get it work currently you are trying to access Views from xml before calling setContentView for setting layout for Activity

Comment: now i get the following 05-24 06:33:23.159: E/AndroidRuntime(886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 06:33:23.159: E/AndroidRuntime(886): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.ListMobileActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-24 06:33:23.159: E/AndroidRuntime(886):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK so what now

Comment: Possible reason: mkdirs() fails and listFiles() returns null.

Comment: add this in AndroidManifest.xml `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Some general rules of advice: Format your code to make it readable. Do not use the initializer, do the work in onCreate(). Do not hardcode "/sdcard", use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and Environment.getExternalStorageState(). Check the line numbers of your stack traces...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in log :

> ListMobileActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must
>   have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

you will need to set  ListView id in xml to 'android.R.id.list' if you are extending ListActivity for creating ListView. do it as `res` layout :

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list" <!--set ListView id to android.R.id.list-->
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

and in code initialize ListView instance as:

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

OR

```
lv =ListMobileActivity.this.getListView();
```

Comment: @user2416330 : yes in res layout xml

Comment: @user2416330 : plz also add xml with question in which u have ListView

Answer (score 1):

If you have asked for **permission in android manifest for reading storage**, then this might be the problem.

It seems from the code that you are querying a instance of list view in the instance block.
This might be called before the setContentView is called. 
You should instantiate a UI component in XML after the layout is inflated or else you will run into exception.

Try this.

```
    public class ListMobileActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.res);

        ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/RootBox");
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

        f.mkdirs();
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
        }

        return MyFiles;
    }

}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import java.io.File;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class ListMobileActivity extends ListActivity {

    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.res);

        ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles("/sdcard/RootBox");

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));
    }

    public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
        ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(DirectoryPath);

        f.mkdirs();
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        if (files.length == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
            }
        }

        return MyFiles;
    }    

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: You will also need to do as @ρяσѕρєяK said regarding your listview.